# Displaying post base on category in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I display the post base in the current category, I can show the category but only one post show.

In my controller:

```
@area_category = Project.joins(:area_category).group(:area_category_id)
```

In my view

```
<% @area_category.each do |category| %>
    <%= category.area_category_name %>
    <% category.project_title %>
<% end %>
```

Basically, i want to display category and post on each category 
Something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>Category 1
    <ul>
      <li>Post 1</li>
      <li>Post 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Category 2
    <ul>
      <li>Post 1</li>
      <li>Post 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

controller

`@area_category = AreaCategory.preload(:projects)`

view

```
<% @area_category.each do |category| %>
<%= category.area_category_name %>
    <% category.projects.each do |project| %>
         <%= project.project_title %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```